# Sending ETH from Mist on testnet does not show up in Metamask account

Tags: mist, testnets

I am doing some test with Mist on the testnet. I am trying to send some ETH to my Metamask account (0xffC6b55a3CaB36D9E7079F8C5dEAfe10e7Ede953) on Ropsten but it never arrives. Here is the transaction in Mist:

[image: Mist transaction]

The transaction is also not visible at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x888d8d0eca7769a4d5f48d37f6fc4fa102abd1dee13ab2ef00ea28b797ee2061

Or any of the other testnets. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was connected to a fork. If that happens do the following:

```
geth --testnet removedb
geth --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

This may have to be done several times. To verify you are on Ropsten compare one of your block hashes to the equivalent block hash at https://ropsten.etherscan.io

Comment: That just deleted all my ether on my account without actually helping...